# Git importing repositories as branches

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have `repo1`, `repo2`, `repo3`, and `repo4`. I want to keep `repo1` and make `repo2`, `repo3`, and `repo4` as different branches of `repo1`, without losing the tags or commits that exist in `repo2`, `repo3`, and `repo4`.

```
repo1-Master branch (contains tags and commits of repo1)
|__branch2 (contains tags and commits of repo2)
|__branch3 (contains tags and commits of repo3)
|__branch4 (contains tags and commits of repo4)
```

Does each of them retain their historical commits, dates, and tags? Can I choose a specific branch to push the code in future, any issues?

Answer (score 2):

It works if your other repos have each one branch (typically master).
You can fetch them in your repo1, and add that master branch as a new *orphan* branch, which will have its own independent history.

```
cd repo1
git remote add repo2 ../path/to/repo2
git fetch repo2
git branch brrepo2 repo2/master
git push -u origin brrepo2
git push --tags
```